# Example of an element of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What would be an example of an element of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$, that isn't a quadratic integer, but its norm in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$ is an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example, $\, w = \dfrac{3+4i}5$ $\           
  $

Note that $\,w\not\in \Bbb Q\,$ has minimum  polynomial $\, (x-w)(x-\bar w) = x^2-(w+\bar w)x + w\bar w\,$ therefore  $\,w\,$ is integral $\iff w+\bar w,\ w\bar w\in\Bbb Z,\,$ i.e. iff its trace and norm are rational integers.

Comment: Can you please explain why? I just started studying this.

Comment: @danaeckoff $3^2+4^2=5^2.$ It is because it is. You just have to compute the norm to see it's an integer.

Comment: @AdamHughes Okay so would  $\frac{5+12i}{13}$ also be another possible answer?

Comment: @danaeckoff yes, exactly.

Comment: @AdamHughes Thank You

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank You too.

Comment: Would such elements be precisely the roots of quadratic equations $aX^2+bX+c\in\mathbb Z[X]$ such that $GCD(a,b,c)=1$, $a\ne \pm 1$, $c\ne 0$, and the discrimant is the opposite of a square?